# Testing a null string does not throw NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, string, nullreferenceexception

This might have been asked already. I'v searched SO and found a few questions on `Null` VS `String.Empty`, but I am curious as why the following statement does not throw a NullReferenceException:

```
String value = null;

if (value != "x") { // does not throw Exception here

    String test = value.Trim(); // throw Exception here as expected

}
```

Comment: Would you expect `if (null != "x")` to throw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Equality` and `Inequality` operators are overloaded for `strings`.So when you do this:

```
value != "x"
```

It calls `System.String::op_Inequality` which calls the `String.Equals` method:

```
public static bool operator != (String a, String b) 
{
    return !String.Equals(a, b);
}
```

And  `String.Equals` is implemented like this:

```
public static bool Equals(String a, String b)
{
    if ((Object)a == (Object)b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if ((Object)a == null || (Object)b == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

As you can see, it casts the `strings` to `object` and returns `false` if one of them is equal to `null`.I assume you confused about why comparing `string` doesn't return `null` because  they are compared by values instead references therefore I share some details.But generally comparing a `null` object with something never throws a `NullReferenceException`.That exception is only thrown if you try to call a method on a `null` object.

Answer (score 2):

Why it should throw Exception?

it throws Exception when you are trying to perform any operation means invoking any memebers of that variable `value`.

```
if (value != "x")
```

basically here you are just comparing its value(null) with `x` which does not throw any exception.

Comment: hmm, strings are compared by it's contents.So, `null` has no content, then what operation is executed actually?

Comment: @Selman22: yes they are compared by their values so `null`(nothing) is not equlas to `x` so if condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this case you are testing if null and "x" are different and this is a valid operation (the result is true obviously).

In the second step you try to call a method on an undefined object, so the exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code with:

```
if (value != null)
{
    ...
}
```

This obviously works for `value` being either null or non-null ("x", say). The comparison in this latter case becomes

```
if ("x" != null)
```

or equivalently

```
if (null != "x")
```

which is equivalent to your original test of

```
if (value != "x")
```

where `value` is null.

It's fine to compare null and non-null values (always false, of course). You can't, however, call a method on a null object as in your example.